# PHP - I dont get any results select query

Tags: php

I have the following class users:

```
class USER
{
    private $db;
    //constructor que estable la conexión con la base de datos
    function __construct($DB_con) {
        $this->db = $DB_con;
    }

    //Estable el login del usuario
    public function login($uname, $upass)
    {
        try 
        {
            $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname");
            $query->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':upass'=>$upass));
            var_dump($query);
```

I dont get any result when I make var_dump($query);

My index.php is the following

```
require_once 'inc/config.php';

//Si el usuario esta logueado

if($user->is_loggedin())
{
    $user->redirect('home.php');
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    var_dump('dentro');
    $uname = $_POST['txt_uname'];
    $upassword = $_POST['txt_password'];
    if($user->login($uname,$upassword))
    {
        $user->redirect('home.php');
    }
    else
    {
        $error = "Nombre de usuario y/o contraseña incorrecto";
    }
}
```

What is the problem?. I try the query in phpmyadmin and I get results.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is there any error? what is the output. please brief a little more! I see you have only condition on user_name and in the params binding you also pass password????

Comment: Include your entire code, such  as your catch block.  If nothing is printed out, it most likely isn't reaching var_dump.

Comment: query should have been something like "SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname" AND user_pass = :upass"

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you suppose to fetch it

 `public function login($uname, $upass)
    {
        try 
        {
            $query = $this->db->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name=:uname");
            $query->execute(array(':uname'=>$uname, ':upass'=>$upass));
            var_dump($query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));`

http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

Comment: var_dump($query) should still print out the object.  So this doesn't really answer the question.

Comment: Also `password=:upass` should be in your prepare statement

Comment: use ` var_dump($query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))`